# Simple way to print pointers in decimal

Tags: c, pointers

I find myself wanting to print out the pointer to a memory address at each given iteration of a function call.  I wish to see if the location in memory is advanced linearly at each iteration (because I suspect this may be the case based on the nature of the API).  Viewing the resultant hexadecimal logs in the console doesn't conveniently help me and so I'd prefer the decimal value.  What is the simplest way of print out these address' decimal value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most purposes `printf("ptr=%d\n", p);` will do it. Sure there may be academic cases where it doesn't work, but 99% of the time it'll be ok.

Edit: ok, so `printf("ptr=%lu\n", (unsigned long)p);` is safer, or even `%llu`.

Comment: actually this is not ok. because a lot of times people have 64 bit machines, and `%d` gets an int (4 bytes) from the `va_list` so you should use a `long` data type that has 64 bits for integers. Memory addresses will be 64 bits sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

To do this portably (in a way that will work even if pointers and `int`s are different sizes, you can use:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

printf("%" PRIuPTR, (uintptr_t)some_pointer);
```

Comment: since you said portably, i must say that the `uintptr_t` is optional

Comment: @self if `uintptr_t` is not provided, it means all of the other solutions proposed so far have undefined behaviour. A solution that works even when `uintptr_t` is not provided, is possible but wouldn't meet OP's criterion of "simple". So I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should cast the pointer to an integer type. A safe way to do it would be to first check the byte sizes of the data types:

```
if(sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(void *)) {
    unsigned long base_10_address = (unsigned long)pointer;
    printf("%lu\n", base_10_address); 
}
```

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour if the pointer cannot be represented as `unsigned long`

Comment: then I should check that sizeof `(void *) == sizeof(long)` before doing the cast